# Spring Security multiple filter chain issue

Tags: rest, spring-security, csrf, csrf-protection

We have a functioning application with multiple filter chain configuration. One of the first filter chains belongs to REST POST requests that requier no authentication:

```
...
<http pattern="/*.info**" entry-point-ref="infoEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" create-session="never">
    <intercept-url pattern="/*.info" access="permitAll" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="infoEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="realmName" value="Info REST Realm" />
</beans:bean>...
```

It worked for GET and POST requests, but after upgrading to Spring Security 4, the POST requests are not captured by this filter chain, but the next filter chain captures them (and creates session and throws 403, doing right its job).

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

CSRF protection is switched on by default in Spring Security, it was switched off by default formerly. The following entry (inside the http tag) solved the problem:

```
<csrf disabled="true"/>
```